# Load Config File

Tags: java

I have a configuration file called config.properties. This file contain many properties for different classes. I'm loading this file in every class and parsing the information nedded for that class.
I would like to know if would be a better approach if I make a config class (static) and then parse all properties there and then on the class just call the class like:

```
Config.ServerPort
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, just do it!

Comment: you already told the solution just apply for it

Answer (score 0):

Put the reading and parsing into a singleton class. Have a look at [Singleton Pattern in Java](http://www.theserverside.de/singleton-pattern-in-java/) if this is new to you.

If you have an IoC container like [spring](http://spring.io), create a service.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to parse the file once and initialize a singleton class and use it everywhere.